# how to call any function in input type text in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have given 2 input text for time selection(FROM and TO) and one button to submit. Initially my button is disabled that means whenever user edit on time FROM and TO my button get enabled. My function name is enable().Below is my code in which I have shown FROM to TO only. I need to call enable() on input or md-input-container.

```
  <md-content class=" pad-hori-27 margin-left66" ng-if="!contactDetails.isAllTime">
    <div>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>From Time</label>
        <input mdc-datetime-picker="" date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time2" placeholder="Time" min-date="minDate" format="HH:mm a" ng-model="contactDetails.timePeriod.fromTime" class=" md-input">
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container>
        <label>To Time</label>
        <input mdc-datetime-picker="" date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time2" placeholder="Time"  min-date="minDate" format="HH:mm a" ng-model="contactDetails.timePeriod.toTime" class=" md-input">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </md-content>
```

Comment: why don't use form validation to this?

Comment: @hadiJz Thanks for your reply. I'm not using these fields in form. These are in List.

Comment: ok. so use in second input `ng-change="enable()"`

Comment: I tried ng-change and ng-click. both not working in my case.

Comment: use ng-change="enable()", and add some log in your enable() function so you can know if its calling your enable() function.

Comment: my enable() is working in all conditions. except above input. ng-change and ng-click is not working in this. Dont know the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ng-change` attribute for this

```
<input mdc-datetime-picker="" md-select="enable()" date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time2" placeholder="Time" min-date="minDate" format="HH:mm a" ng-model="contactDetails.timePeriod.fromTime" class=" md-input">
```

you can create a watch on collection like this:

```
$scope.$watch('contactDetails.timePeriod.fromTime', function(newValues, oldValues){
  if(newValues != oldValues) {
    $scope.enable();
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried ng-change and ng-click. both not working in my case

Comment: I have updated my answer replaced ng-change with md-select, may be this will work.

Comment: I tried to appy $watch but didn't understand how ? I possible can you please give small code.I want to understand $watch Thank you.

Comment: watch takes two parameters, first model-name as string and second callback function with new and old value. whenever model change its trigger automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ans. If i add this code in my controller then it will work or I will need to do call or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

you can call function with the help of ng-change or ng-click directive

like as

```
<input mdc-datetime-picker="" ng-change="enable()" date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time2" placeholder="Time" min-date="minDate" format="HH:mm a" ng-model="contactDetails.timePeriod.fromTime" class=" md-input">
```

but In place of call function to enable button you can you angular js form validation 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: I tried ng-change and ng-click. both not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need to call enable at each change the input.
Instead, use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) on your button, providing a function testing that FROM and/or TO are filled.

If you really need to call enable on change, use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

*EDIT* (to detail the solution)
For what it's worth, here is what I suggested.

```js
angular.module('changeExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = '';
    $scope.disable = function() {
      return $scope.value === '';
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="changeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="value" ng-model="value" id="ng-change-example1" />
    <button ng-disabled="disable()">Submit</button>
    <p>
      Value is "{{value}}" (activated: {{!disable()}})
    </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Note that this is a standard way to do it with Angular, instead of rely on *$watch* as suggested.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I tried ng-change and ng-click. both not working in my case